# How binding is a signed Offer from a USA-based firm in Germany?

Tags: united-states, contracts, germany

I'm in Germany. Shortly I got a job offer from a USA-based firm. I've signed this offer. The firm currently registers a german business entity registered and active at the end of Mai 2022. After registering is accomplished, I get a german job agreement (a contract which follows german contracting rules). But, I should quit my current job ASAP to enter the new position in June.

This offer looks seriously - but I have never seen such; I was always working for german employers. I have attached here the last page of the offer.[image]

My questions are not about any kind of legal advice. I want rather know:

- is somebody familiar with such offers?
- Is it a kind of usual procedure to issue and sign an offer on USA employing market?
- If you signed an offer with other employer, how many percent of probability would you give that you in fact begin with this job?

Comment: Regardless of how binding it is, are they able to fire you whenever they want?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Sure, they are able to fire me while the usual trial period, it is normal - contracts are not limited in the time, but have six months trial. My question is rather: in Germany is a signed contract a 100% guarantee, that one begins with the job. Is the signed offer guarantees the same?

Comment: Even if the contract was 100% sealed and confirmed, couldn't they just fire you even before you begin? So the concept is a bit pointless, is it not?

Comment: You might have legal rights, but try suing a US company and getting money out of them while you are in Germany.

Comment: @nvoigt Answered my question. Looks like you get two weeks wages, and unemployment benefits if you were technically employed.

Comment: @Evgeniy: if you trust them so little, you should perhaps not work for them at all. If you think fear will break their commitments during the hiring, why wouldn't they mistreat you once you hired too?

Comment: @Hilmar It is not a question about whether I trust them. I just don't know, like what should I treat this kind of document "offer". Just never seen it. For somebody from USA it could be an absolut normal thing, where you go and quit the current job without any doubts.

Comment: @Hilmar Why would they have any reason to trust their (hopefully) future employer? You can trust they will do whatever is most beneficial for the company, but beyond that, there is not much you can trust.

Comment: What happens to you if something goes wrong with this company's registration in Germany and it can't be resolved until November?

Comment: Now why would a document involving the US and Germany be dated in Moscow time? That feels off…

Comment: Your edits move this question from "legal advice" to "opinion based" so it's still badly off-topic here I'm afraid.

Answer (score 6):

Well, nothing is really *binding*. Even if the contract is written in blood of their first born, nobody can be *forced* to employ you. Corporations *can* be forced to pay you though as if you had been terminated by the rules of your contract.

For a German contract, it is customary to have a probation period of 6 months (that is the legal maximum) in which any party can terminate the contract with no specific reason and two weeks notice.

So if you *had* a German contract from a German entity, you would have a "binding" contract insofar as you would be entitled to two weeks pay in case they decide to not do this.

Without a German contract, I don't know what would be binding about a piece of paper. You cannot force them to employ you and this piece has no mention of what happens if they don't go through with it, so likely "nothing".

So binding or not, they can let you go at any time in the next six months and the difference is two weeks of pay in case you get a German contract from a German entity. Plus you would be entitled to unemployment benefits, I'm not sure if the Amt would accept a piece of paper with no legal meaning as a prove that you did not just quit your job on your own.

Whether you want that security or not is up to you. For me, I would wait until they have figured out the legal stuff. Sign when they have a German contract when they have set up a German entity. Any paper before that is about worth as much as a friendly email.

Comment: Good advice on waiting for the legal body/entity of this US-based company to set up shop in Germany - everything else will be way to risky. Let them register and have them send a legally binding offer according to German labour-laws first - then hand in the notice once the new gig is all set up..